# change img src in a div on load

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML, and i m trying to accomplish two things.
 1. Onload change the first item image to 1-B.png
 2. If any of the other links are click ed then change the image to reflect what has been clicked.

```
<ul class="tabs">
<div class="q1"><a href="#"><img src="/visuals/1-A.png" border="0" alt="" /></a></div>
<div class="q2"><a href="#"><img src="/visuals/2-A.png" border="0" alt="" /></a></div>
<div class="q3"><a href="#"><img src="/visuals/3-A.png" border="0" alt="" /></a></div>
<div class="q4"><a href="#"><img src="/visuals/4-A.png" border="0" alt="" /></a></div>
</ul>
```

I used the following for the onload but it doesn't change

```
$('ul.tabs > .q1 > .current > a:first').click(function(e){
      $('.q1').attr('src',('/visuals/1-B.png'));
});
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does ANY image change or is the entire script "broken"? You could try with an `onclick`on each img and then calling a function to change the images (using JQUery or not). If NONE of the images works, make sure your SRC is pointing to the right location. Check this with Firebug and look if the images gets loaded or if you get and error when you try to change the images.

Comment: $('ul.tabs > .q1 > .current > a:first').click(function(e){
      $('.q1').html('<a href="#"><img src="/visuals/1-B.png" border="0" alt="" /></a>'));
});

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to change the image that is inside the `<div>`:

```
$('.q1 img').attr(...)
```

To "reset" all other images, you can have such code:

```
$(".tabs div").not(".q1").each(function(index) {
   $(this).find("img").attr('src', '/visuals/' + index + '-A.png');
});
```

Comment: ZzzZzZzz... Can't believe I missed that :)

Comment: Thank that worked a treat, how would i be able to do this for the other items if clicked. If i click on 3 then set all back to A and only set 3 as b??

Comment: Congratulations on reaching 10K, by the way `:)`

Comment: Thanks @Kobi I feel.. powerful! ;)

Answer (score 3):

try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.q1 img').attr('src',('/visuals/1-B.png'));
    $('.q1 a').click(function(){
        $(this).attr('src',(...what u want...));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("div-1 > img").attr('href', image.link);
    $("div-1 > img").attr('src', image.src);
});
```

Addition to above:

```
var src  = $('.rg-image img').attr('src');
```

OR

```
var src  = $('.rg-image').find('img').attr('src');
```

OR

```
var src=$('.rg-image').children("img").attr('src');
```